# Returning the value from a select_tag as a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby form with a text box for start_date and one for end date.  I need to add a dropdown for status.  I added the select_tag and it populates correctly.  My problem is how do I get the value that was selected?

Snippet from form:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">From</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= text_field_tag "purchase_requests_from_time", Date.today.beginning_of_month, :class => "text date_picker report_start_time_picker" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">To</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= text_field_tag "purchase_requests_to_time", Date.today.end_of_month, :class => "text date_picker report_start_time_picker" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Status</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(get_purchase_request_statuses) %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Status2</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= select_tag "status2", options_for_select(get_purchase_request_statuses) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then when I try to access the params in the controller

```
from_time = params[:purchase_requests_from_time]
to_time = params[:purchase_requests_to_time]
status = params[:status]
status2 = params[:status2]
```

The time parameters show up fine, the status and status2 parameters are missing.

```
params = {ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess} ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess (4 elements)
 'purchase_requests_from_time' = "Tue Mar 01, 2016"
 'purchase_requests_to_time' = "Thu Mar 31, 2016"
 'action' = "export"
 'controller' = "purchase_requests"
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is get_purchase_request_statuses returning an array of strings? If not, make sure the output of that function is an array. 

Also, are you sure you're not filtering the params in the controller with a `params.require().permit()` statement before they get to the point where you're inspecting them? If you are, make sure :status and :status2 are arguments of the permit method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  1)  The get_purchase_request_statuses is returning an array and is populating the drop down list correctly.  2) I don't have a params.require statement anywhere within my code.  Should I?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  I was missing the form_tag and was using a link_to rather than a submit_tag.  This is the code that works

```
<div class="modal hide" id="download_purchase_requests">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Download Purchase Requests</h3>
  </div>
  <%= form_tag({:action => :export, :controller => :purchase_requests}, :multipart => true) do %>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">From</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= text_field_tag "purchase_requests_from_time", Date.today.beginning_of_month, :class => "text date_picker report_start_time_picker" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">To</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= text_field_tag "purchase_requests_to_time", Date.today.end_of_month, :class => "text date_picker report_start_time_picker" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Status</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= select_tag :purchase_request_status, options_for_select(get_purchase_request_statuses, :selected => params[:purchase_request_status]) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <%= submit_tag "Download", :class => "btn", :id => "download-btn", :onsubmit => "$('#download-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```